# Getting the items from a mulitple select ListView WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I need help from getting the selected value of multiple items in a listview.

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lb_employees" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="140" Margin="141,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Loaded="lb_employees_Loaded" SelectionChanged="lb_employees_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Employee ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=empid}" Width="0" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Here is how I populate the ListView:

```
dbml.hrdbDataContext listpeople = new dbml.hrdbDataContext();
        var q = from p in listpeople.EmpIDs
                join pi in listpeople.EmpBasicFiles on p.EmpID1 equals pi.EBF_EmpID
                where pi.EBF_Active == 1
                orderby p.LastName
                select new classes.Employeeselected() { FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, empid = p.EmpID1 };

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            this.lb_employees.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

How can I get the value of let’s say, empid when selected?

I have already tried this code, but it’s not working at all.

```
        private void lb_employees_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (classes.Employeeselected item in lb_employees.SelectedItems)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item.empid.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"it’s not working at all"* -- please be much more specific about what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

So odd. When I compiled it before, it kept giving me a null exception error. But now, it seems work just fine!

After a reboot, it seems to be working just fine. Maybe it was a problem with this Insider Build?

Comment: Who knows. However, instead of answering you could have deleted your question. It will unlikely be of any help for others.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be great help for others. I've been searching for something for about 2 days now. I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow.

Comment: But in your question you didn't even tell what exactly did not work. That's completely useless.

Comment: Useless question, non-answer. Nobody can learn anything from it because you refused to say what was actually wrong and you don't know what you changed that fixed it.